# How do I make my webpages main content clickable/accessible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is fully functional outside of the simple fact that I can't click the chat box or use it, even though it is the main content of the front page. I think it's safe to say that any other content I would put there would not be clickable as well[a youtube video, etc..].

Here's the sites HTML, and I'll link you the CSS at the bottom of the page:

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Geo" rel="stylesheet"> 
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Sleeperz.us</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sleeperz.us/css/main.css">
   </head>
   <div align="center">
    <div class="contentContainer">
    <div style="width": 1000px; word-wrap: break-word; margin: auto; style="color": #000; style="align": center;><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/index.html"><img src="http://sleeperz.us/imgs/sleeperz-wide.png" width="auto" height="auto"></a>
   <div align="center">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/data.html">DATA</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/about.html">About</a></li>
   <div class="dropdown">
  <li class="dropbtn"><li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/nightcore-creator.html">NIGHTCORE Creator</a>
    <a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/artwork.html">Artwork</a>
    <a href="http://blog.sleeperz.us">My Blog</a>
    </div>
   </div> 
   </ul> </div>
   <p align="center" style="text-align: center; font-family: arial; font-color: #efefef; style="width: 960px;"><p font color="#efefef"><font color="#ff0000">
   <p align="left"><font color="#E2E2D8"><font face="Yu Gothic">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//www3.smartchatbox.com/shoutbox/start.php?key=831990491"></script>
   <footer><div class="footer">
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><p font size="8px"><p font face="Yu Gothic"><font  color="#efefef">2017    www.sleeperz.us (c)</p>
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    </footer></div></p>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sleeperz.us/imgs/favicon.ico"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS file: [http://www.sleeperz.us/css/main.css](http://www.sleeperz.us/css/main.css/)

Comment: Your chatbox appears to be working fine -- you register an account, sign in, and are able to send a message. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Your css file is throwing 404

Comment: This markup is terrible. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Akane are you using [smart chat](http://www3.smartchatbox.com/faq?)
*, Have you paid for their service and gone through their documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a lot of errors in your HTML. There was two style tags for a few divs, body tag was missing as well.

Main thing was you had your UL at 100% height. Removing that as well as the above fixes give the result below.

```css
body {
 margin: -50px auto;
 font-family: "Yu Gothic", sans-serif;
 background-color: #000000;
 background-image: url(http://sleeperz.us/backgrounds/wallpaper.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
 background-size: cover;
 text-align: left;
 font-size:12px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
 background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    width: 960px;
 /*height: 100%;*/
 font-size:19px;
 font-family: Geo;
}

li {
text-align: center;
color: #e7010b;
background-color: transparent;
}

li a {
 float: left;
    display: block;    
 padding: 20px;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    transition: .5s;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: transparent;
}



a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e7010b;
  background-color: transparent;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
 transition: .4s;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #efefef;
    padding: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
 float: left;
    display: relative;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 260px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 top: 65px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 transition: .4s;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.main {
 align: center;
    padding: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    height: auto; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
 text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
}

.contentContainer {
       width:1000px; 
       height: 1100px auto; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
    background-position: center;
    min-height: calc(120% - 300px);
    margin: 0px;
}
 
footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
 
#background_cycler{padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1}
#background_cycler img{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;z-index:1}
#background_cycler img.active{z-index:3}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
   <html>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Geo" rel="stylesheet"> 
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Sleeperz.us</title>
    </head>
   <div align="center">
    <div class="contentContainer">
    <div style="width: 1000px; word-wrap: break-word; margin: auto;color: #000;"><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/index.html"><img src="http://sleeperz.us/imgs/sleeperz-wide.png" width="auto" height="auto"></a>
   <div align="center">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/data.html">DATA</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/about.html">About</a></li>
   <div class="dropdown">
  <li class="dropbtn"><li><a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/nightcore-creator.html">NIGHTCORE Creator</a>
    <a href="http://www.sleeperz.us/artwork.html">Artwork</a>
    <a href="http://blog.sleeperz.us">My Blog</a>
    </div>
   </div> 
   </ul> </div>
   <p align="center" style="text-align: center; font-family: arial; font-color: #efefef;width: 960px;"><p font color="#efefef"><font color="#ff0000">
   <p align="left"><font color="#E2E2D8"><font face="Yu Gothic">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//www3.smartchatbox.com/shoutbox/start.php?key=831990491"></script>
   <footer><div class="footer">
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><p font size="8px"><p font face="Yu Gothic"><font  color="#efefef">2017    www.sleeperz.us (c)</p>
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p></div>
   </footer></p>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sleeperz.us/imgs/favicon.ico"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It worked great, and I also took advice from the other answers. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

First you are are missing the start body tag `<body>`
**AND**

```
<div style="width": 1000px; word-wrap: break-word; margin: auto; style="color": #000; style="align": center;>
```

has to be like

```
<div style="width: 1000px; word-wrap: break-word; margin: auto; color: #000;" align= "center">
```

and read about how to use the font tag attributes **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp)**. The way you are using is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make my webpages main content clickable/accessible?

Write valid HTML, and don't cover the whole window with an invisible element.

You have an unordered list that is covering the whole window. This markup is terrible and needs to be completely rewritten.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Geo;
}
```

On top of this specific problem, things like `align: center` aren't valid in HTML5.

Comment: This is likely also related to the missing body tag as mentioned by @Kuru